# Botão voltar do navegador apagar uma classe

Tags: jquery, html5-history

Estou fazendo um site que funciona em uma página única. Então quando clico em um botão do menu ele rola até a área que quero com:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#nomedoid').offset().top},Math.abs(0));
```

E ao mesmo tempo coloco o window.history.pushState:

```
window.history.pushState(null, 'blablabla', 'link');
```

Funciona como eu esperava, se eu clicar no botão voltar do navegador (ou celular) o site volta pra última "página" do site, inclusive rolando (scroll) pra ela.

O PROBLEMA: Existe agora uma "página" que abre sobre o site, entra uma div na frente  do site com addClass e também dou o window.history.pushState:

```
$('.frente_site').addClass('frente_site_aparece');
window.history.pushState(null, 'blablabla', 'link-frente');
```

Aí se dou um voltar no navegador a URL até muda, mas ele não da o removeClass na class '.frente_site'. Teria como fazer isso acontecer? Estou fazendo da forma errada?

Comment: Estás a mudar o quê no url mais precisamente? A hash? ex: `www.exemplo.com#div1`, `www.exemplo.com#div2` etc...?

Comment: Não, mudo de www.site.com.br para www.site.com.br/link-frente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei descobrindo uma forma, se não for a ideal me avisem!

Usei essa função:

```
window.onpopstate = function (event) {
    if(qualLink == 'perfil'){
        // faz algo
    }
}
```

Só alimento a variável qualLink toda vez que mudo a URL e depois verifico ela com o onpopstate.